# vim - how to NOT automatically switch buffer with :cn and :cb

Tags: list, vim, buffer

I use the quickfix list to store errors. But i hate when it automatically jump to different buffers when pressing :cn or :cb. I want to press Enter myself to jump to location. Is there any solution ?
Thx.

Comment: I’m not sure what else you would want `:cn` to do. Could you more clearly describe your problem? Maybe a set of reproducible steps would be insightful.

Comment: Sure i will try to explain myself with my poor english. So i use the quickfix list to store the g++ compiler errors. I like to use :cn because it avoid all the useless lines between the errors lines (and i can't do it with <down> or j). I like to have several tabs open and i use set switchbuf+=usetab,newtab. Which means that :cn auto jump to another tab and i have no time to browse the quickfix list. I want to be able to  jump to new tab when ever i press <Enter> on a error line. I hope this is understandable :)

Comment: @TanguyLissenko, then the behaviour of `:cn` is not the problem, it's your `:help errorformat` that is broken and should be fixed. You should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of `:cnext` is precisely to jump to *the next entry* in the quickfix *list*. If that's not what you want, then don't use it.

Navigating to *the next line* in the quickfix *window* is done with `<Down>` or `j`.